# Simple DOM open Redirection quesiton

Tags: redirect, dom

Burp highlights DOM open redirection possible with code below. Could anyone explain if this is feasible? Many thanks!

```
var url = window.location.href;
url = url.replace(/(\?|\&)user_lang=[A-Za-z]{2}/, "");
window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Most likely a false positive

Let's have a look at what the code exactly does: First, it reads the current URL, then it applies some Regular Expression to it, and finally it redirects to that URL. Burp recognizes this pattern and flags it as potential vulnerability.

Let's have a closer look at the regular expression: `(\?|\&)user_lang=[A-Za-z]{2}`

So the first match is either a `?` or a `&`, followed by `user_lang=`, followed by two letters of either upper- or lower case. Here are some strings this would match to:

`&user_lang=FO`
`?user_lang=sj`
`?user_lang=Oo`

Once a match is found, it is replaced with nothing, and the user is redirected to the resulting URL. Let's look at an example:

`https://example.com/?user_lang=ENsome/kind/of/url` would rresult in a redirect to `https://example.com/some/kind/of/url`

This should *generally* not be a problem, as redirects to a different domain are not a problem using this method.

Comment: Thanks MechMK1! Good explanation. The last sentence is a bit hard to understand - you mean such redirection does not allow redirection to other domains, right? Thanks!

Comment: @sssseossss Exactly. I can redirect to `example.com/whatever`, but not `evil.com`